# Reset code coloring in Dreamweaver CS6

Tags: dreamweaver, color-scheme

I recently installed DW CS6 via Adobe Creative Cloud - and seems to have attempted to import my code coloring from CS5 - but not to much success, It's a jumped mess really. I'm hoping i don't have to go through each color setting and recolor it - I'm hoping there's a simple reset switch?

If someone has a dark code color setting (for CS6) they could share i'd be happy with that as well.

Thanks.

Comment: Check out [this](http://www.thatwebguyblog.com/post/a_dark_code_view_theme_for_dreamweaver/) I installed it, but it didn't work out well with jquery so deleted it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put new Colors.xml into:

C:\Users[yourname]\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Dreamweaver CS6[yourlang]\Configuration\CodeColoring\